# $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ in $BV(\mathbb{R})$, then $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> A function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is said a bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$ if it is in $BV([a,b])$ for all $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$ and results $$V(f):=\sup_{-\infty<a<b <+\infty} V_a^b(f)<\infty.$$

We say that if $f\in BV[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$, I must prove that

$$f\in BV(\mathbb{R})\implies f\;\text{bounded on}\;\mathbb{R}$$

**My solution**

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then exist $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ such that $x\in [a,b]$. Considering the partition $\mathcal{P}=\{a\le x\le b\}$ we have that $$|f(x)|\le |f(a)|+V_a^b(f,\mathcal{P})\le |f(a)|+V_a^b(f),$$ where $V_a^b(f)$ is the sup on all partitions of $[a,b]$. From here, I don't know how to conclude. Could anyone suggest me something?

Comment: We have $|f(x)-f(0)|\leq V_0^x(f)\leq V(f)$ for all $x>0$ and $|f(0)-f(x)|\leq V_x^0(f)\leq V(f)$ for $x<0$, hence $|f(x)|\leq |f(0)|+V(f)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, implying the boundedness of $f$.

Comment: You wrote 'for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, exists $a,b\cdots$'. So in your estimation $$|f(x)|\le |f(a)|+V_a^b(f),$$ the RHS depends on $x$. So your attempt is probably not feasible. $a,b$ should be fixed, like Feng's comment.